# Ordering of custom Django middleware

Tags: django, django-middleware

In a Django app, I have two middlewares.

One is called `NoWWWRedirectMiddleware`, it's purpose is to redirect `www` to `no www`.

The second is called `XForwardedForMiddleware`. It populates `REMOTE_ADDR` with the first value of `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` (if it exists).

My question is about middleware ordering in `settings.py`. Currently, I have it ordered like so:

```
'myproj.middleware.NoWWWRedirect.NoWWWRedirectMiddleware',
'myproj.middleware.XForwardedFor.XForwardedForMiddleware',
################## Other Middleware ###################
'user_sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
```

My question is: shouldn't the top two be the other way around? I'm hazy about how to order them, and am currently going with gut feel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#middleware-order-and-layering):

> During the request phase, before calling the view, Django applies middleware in the order it’s defined in MIDDLEWARE, top-down.

so it seems your ordering is correct - if the user is to be redirected to `no www`, no sense in setting the remote address variable. As a side note - redirecting from `www` to `no www` should be done by the web server (Apache / Nginx), it will be more efficient that way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My webserver's nginx (reverse proxy in front of gunicorn). Why would you say redirecting from nginx is better than middleware? Care to add some notes on that too.

Comment: With redirecting in the middleware nginx has to pass the request to django, django has to process it and send back redirect and finally nginx has to pass the reply to the client - you have three steps, every one taking time and resources. With redirecting done by nginx there is only one step - nginx receives the request and immediately replies with the redirect.